# How to set engineering format on x axis plotly

Tags: plotly, number-formatting

Plotly express labels 1e9 values as "B" suffix. I want to use Si notation i.e "G' instead of "B"

Answer (score 2):

https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis

fig_df is a dataframe of x and y columns

```
fig = px.line(fig_df,x='x',y=['y'])
fig.update_xaxes(exponentformat="SI")
```